# change baseurl with okhttp

Tags: java, okhttp

Recently,When I plan to rewrite mine company program. I use the RxJava+OkHttp+Retrofit. But I have a problem.

1. Our application has only one access interface which can provide the base address for all modules. The format is as follows.

[image]

2. My intention is to dynamically replace baseurl with interceptors, the code reads as follows:

[image]

That's my code but I found a question,the converted URL becomes so:
`www.xxapi.com:80/authorize/login/{#version code}` (This is wrong).

This is wrong. This version field should be behind the base address.The correct url like this:
`www.xxapi.com:80/{#version code}/authorize/login` (This is right).

I've tried many ways, and I can't change the location of the version field.

I really don't know how to go on,I'm sorry.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry,I used it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the call to `addPathSegment(version)` with a call to `setPathSegment(0, version)`.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.Builder.html#setPathSegment-int-java.lang.String-

Comment: If I write that way,it will become :                                    www.xxapi.com:80/{#version code}/login.                                                            The first path field is replaced。

Comment: Thank you, teacher,I seem to have found a good idea.by request.url().segments();I can get a List collection,Thank you。